# How to multilevel base64 decoder and show proper php code

Tags: php, base64, php-codebrowser

How to multilevel base64 decoder and show proper php code....

i.e.....

```
 base64_decode(
    base64_decode(
       'SkhSb2FYTXRQazh3TUU4d01FOVBUMDh3VDA4Z1BTQm1ZV3h6WlRzZ0NRa2tUekF3VDA4d1R6QXdUMDh3VHlBOUlITjBjblJ2Ykc5M1pYSW9jSEpsWjE5eVpYQnNZV05sS0dKaGMyVTJORjlrWldOdlpHVW9KMGw1T0hWTGFWRnFKeWtzSUNjbkxDQWtYMU5GVWxaRlVsdGlZWE5sTmpSZlpHVmpiMlJsS0NkVk1GWlRWbXRXVTFneFFsTlVNVkpRVVRBNVRTY3BYU2twT3c9PQ=='
     )
  );
```

Any buddy have php script to decode multi level base64_decode() and show proper php code.

Comment: Removed unnecessary braces

Comment: What is your actual problem?  echoing your code snippet looks like all you need.  What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

Encoded string will be decoded to exact string if the string encoded or decoded equal no. of times. 
It means two level encoded string can be decoded 2 level.

```
<?php
$string="Hello Stack Overflow";
echo $encodedString=base64_encode(base64_encode($string));//Multilevel(2) encode
echo base64_decode(base64_decode($encodedString));//Multilevel(2) decode
```

Comment: When I decode file there is two level encoded code. Please decode below code.        if ($O0O00O00000OO = trim($_GET[base64_decode(base64_decode('WTJsMGVRPT0='))])) {
                eval(base64_decode(base64_decode('SkhSb2FYTXRQazh3TURBd1QwOHdNRTh3TURBZ1BTQjBjbWx0S0hOMVluTjBjaWdrVHpCUE1EQlBNREF3TURCUFR5d2dNQ3dnTWlrcE93PT0=')));
                eval(base64_decode(base64_decode('SkhSb2FYTXRQazlQTURBd01EQXdNRTh3TUU4Z1BTQjBjbWx0S0hOMVluTjBjbDl5WlhCc1lXTmxLQ1JQTUU4d01FOHdNREF3TUU5UExDQW5KeXdnTUN3Z01pa3BPdz09')));
            }

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a function similar to this:

```
function multiBase64Decode($string, int $iteration = 1){
    for($i=0;$i<$iteration;$i++){
        $string = base64_decode($string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```